# Pyserial to interect arduino code is not functioning

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, pyserial

I developed two version of code to interact with arduino. Version 1:-

```
import urllib
import sys
from time import sleep
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
#ser.open()
while True:
    sock = urllib.urlopen('http://pro*******.com')
    htmlSource = sock.read()
    z = str(htmlSource)
    l = z[0] + z[1]
    sock.close()
    print l
    if l == 'On':
        counter = '1'
    else:
        counter = '0'
    ser.write(counter)

    time.sleep(4)
ser.close()
print "safe to close"
```

problem with this one is when i close the program it keeps running the serial port so if I want to use it again heave to restart my pc. So I developed another version to using keybordinterupt but for this one serial write function is not working. I dont know what is wrong with my code . Is there any one to help me with this ? 
Version 2:

```
import urllib
import sys
from time import sleep
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
try:
    while True:
        sock = urllib.urlopen('http://pro*******.com')
        htmlSource = sock.read()
        z = str(htmlSource)
        l = z[0] + z[1]
        sock.close()
        print l
        print "Please enter CTL+C to stop"
        if l == 'On':
            ser.write('1')

        else:
            ser.write('0')

        time.sleep(4)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
ser.close()
print "safe to close"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code inside of a Class and Instantiate that class and call the methods.

```
import urllib
import sys
from time import sleep
import serial
import time

class ArduinoSerial:

    def __init__(self, port, baudRate):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudRate)
        self.stop = False
        #self.ser.open()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:    
            sock = urllib.urlopen('http://pro*******.com')
            htmlSource = sock.read()
            z = str(htmlSource)
            l = z[0] + z[1]
            sock.close()
            print l
            if l == 'On':
                counter = '1'
            else:
                counter = '0'
            self.ser.write(counter)

            time.sleep(4)

    def stop(self):
        self.stop = True
        ser.close()
        print "safe to close"

arduinoSerial = ArduinoSerial('COM4', 9600)
try:
    arduinoSerial.run();
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    arduinoSerial.stop();
    print "Recieved Kill Command. Quitting"
    sys.exit(0)

# Just to be safe   
arduinoSerial.stop();
```

Comment: please check bellow comment

Comment: Serial write or read is not working properly some times it works and some time its not and When i keyboard interrupt it shows following error :- 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\versityproject\pythoncode\newd.py", line 39, in <module>
    arduinoSerial.stop();
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable